# Modularize functions between files in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am miss understanding this concept in nodejs.  I want to place a function in a folder at ./models/user lets say to represent a model I use for user.  Then I want to use these as functions somewhere else.  The issue I always run into is when do something like user.something it doesn't handle like a function.  I am misunderstanding how this works.

The model would look something like this:

```
//model/user.js
function User() {
    this.foo = null;
}

User.prototype.hashPass = function (password, callback) {
    //Code that hashes a password
    callback(err, hash);
};

User.prototype.insertUser = function (email, password, callback) {
    //Code that inserts a user and returns some 'done' callback
    callback(err, done);
};

module.exports = User;
```

And somewhere else in my program lets say passport.js I want to do this:

```
//config/passport.js
var User = require('../models/user);
var user = new User();

async.waterfall([
    //how does this look
    //EDIT ATTEMPTED HERE
    user.hashPass(password, function(err, result) {

    }),
    user.insertUser(result, function(err, rows) {

    })
], //some callback );
```

Made some edits to help to clarify what I am trying to accomplish here.

EDIT:
This link shows how to do [async waterfalls with multiple callbacks](https://github.com/caolan/async#waterfall)

Code based on EDIT / Understanding:

```
async.series([
  function(callback) {
    user.hashPass(password, function(err, result) {
      callback(err,result);
    })
  }
], function(err, result) {
  if (err) return err;
  console.log('test',result);
});
```

Comment: Don't rush SO, read official docs first

Comment: Is your question really "how does async.waterfall work?" ?

Comment: Yes and no. I understood async waterfall at a low level but I didn't understand how to make them work with functions from other modules.

Comment: In your scenario, I would not even use async - I've updated my answer below to show you how you can invoke functions from other modules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing you need to change in your code is to replace the line

```
module.exports = User;
```

in your `passport.js` file by

```
var User = require('../model/User');
```

Then you can invoke the functions on user:

```
user.hashPass(password, function(err, result) {
    user.insertUser(result, function(err, rows) {
      // do something with rows here
    });
});
```

Comment: I had thought about this, but in my case there would be about 4 callbacks creating a callback hell.  If it were just one you are 100% correct. Therefore I am using async to keep the code somewhat flat.  I am too new to JS to use promises for now to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2):

It's not working because you have to 'require' your module in the file you want to use it in and you're creating object methods on a constructor function that does not exist. Instead, you could create a user object (not a constructor function) and set each function to an object property, like this:

```
//module file
var user = {
  hashPass: function(password, callback){
   //password-hashing function 
  },
  insertUser: function(email, password, callback){
  //new user function
  }
};

module.exports = user;
```

Then, in whatever place you want to use it, you do so like this:

```
//some other file
var user = require(path-to-module);

user.hashPass(); //pass in all parameters (password, callback)
user.insertUser(); //pass in all parameters (password, callback)
```

The only potential hang-up about this method is that you'll have to define all of your parameters before calling either object property.

Comment: I have edited to include the require, my question was never meant to target that piece this is why i specified the comment "how does this look". I don't understand how to call this as a function within the waterfall, how the parameter pass in, and how the callback works.

Answer (score 1):

When we have been requiring custom modules we require them by path .

```
var User = require('config/passport');
var user = new User();

async.waterfall([
   //how does this look
   //do hashPass here
  ,
  //do insertPass here
], //some callback );
```